# jQuery conditional code not working as expected: returns 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am checking to see if there are previous and / or next elements in my code. Everything works fine unless I click the first element.

When I click on an image I'm able to change the source of the image in .mainNav. I'm going to be using my getThePrevAndNextImages() function for something else later.

What I'm expecting to see when I click on the first element is:

```
console.log('there isnt a prev img');
console.log('the next image is: ' + nextImg);
```

But instead all I get is `there isnt a prev img`.

When I then do `console.log(nextImg)` I get `undefined` - but according to my code there IS a nextImg, so should `console.log()` it, surely?

What's wrong with my code?

```
$(function () {
    $('.filmstrip img').on('click', function () {
        var new_src = $(this).attr('data-src');
        $('.mainView img.current').attr('src', new_src);
        getThePrevAndNextImages(this);
    });

    function getThePrevAndNextImages(obj) {
        //get the previous element's data source
        var prevImg = $(obj).closest("li + *").prev().find('img').attr('data-src');
        if (prevImg === undefined) {
            console.log('there isnt a prev img');
        }
        if (prevImg != undefined) {
            console.log('the previous image is: ' + prevImg);
        }
        //get the next element's data source
        var nextImg = $(obj).closest("li + *").next().find('img').attr('data-src');
        if (nextImg === undefined & prevImg != undefined) {
            console.log('You are at the last image');
        }
        if (nextImg != undefined) {
            console.log('the next image is: ' + nextImg);
        }
    }
});
```

my HTML:

```
<ul class="mainView">
    <li><img class="previous" src="1-large.png" alt=""></li>            
    <li><img class="current" src="3-large.png" alt=""></li>         
    <li><img class="next" src="2-large.png" alt=""></li>
</ul>
<ul class="filmstrip">
    <li><img src="1-small.png" data-src="1-large.png" alt=""></li>          
    <li><img src="2-small.png" data-src="2-large.png" alt=""></li>          
    <li><img src="3-small.png" data-src="3-large.png" alt=""></li>          
    <li><img src="4-small.png" data-src="4-large.png" alt=""></li>          
    <li><img src="5-small.png" data-src="5-large.png" alt=""></li>          
    <li><img src="6-small.png" data-src="6-large.png" alt=""></li>          
</ul>
```

Comment: Show your HTML and we can help further.

Comment: Done, it's in my original question now, apologies.

Comment: instead of `$(obj).closest("li + *")` try `$(obj).parent()`

Comment: when you say "When i then do console.log(nextImg) I get undefined" do you mean you are doing this in the javascript console of your browser?  That would be a scope issue.

Comment: No, I'm doing it in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change:

```
var nextImg = $(obj).closest("li + *").next().find('img').attr('data-src');
```

to:

```
var nextImg = $(obj).closest("li").next().find('img').attr('data-src');
```

Your selector `li + *` has no meaning. Seem like you want to target closest `li` instead.

Comment: Thank you Felix, this worked. I imagine it's a difference between how .next() and .prev() work.

Comment: It's not matter of `.prev()` and `.next()`. See explanation in ly answer below.

Answer (score 1):

With your

```
closest('li + *')
```

you are selecting the li item next to the parent li, not the parent element itself.

Given your HTML code, when you click on `<img src="5-small.png" data-src="5-large.png" alt="" />`.

Your

```
$(obj).closest("li + *")
```

will be your last `li` element and

```
$(obj).closest("li + *").next()
```

will be an empty jQuery object which result to an undefined when your retriev the `data-src` attribute.

Read about `the sibling selector` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp).

Hope it's clear enough for all.